# Как реализовать неограниченное количество под доменов через .htacces?

Tags: .htaccess, php

Есть такие мысли, но реализовать сам не смогу. Допустим, есть сайт site.ru и его под домен name.site.ru. В директиве под домена есть файл index.php с кодом

```
if (isset($_GET['name']))      {$name= $_GET['name'];}
echo $name;
```

и теперь при заходе на сайт `name.site.ru/index.php?name=petya`, то выведется Petya.
Как добиться этой же надписи, перейдя по ссылке petya.site.ru, используя файл .htacces?

Comment: Уважаемый хэшкод исправьте .htaccess в названии

Comment: Вы занимаетесь не теми вещами: это называется субдомены. Есть статьи по автоматическим субдоменам, более того, такая тема уже была - ищите, там есть ответ уже.

Answer (score 3):

Что-то типа

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]+\.)?site\.ru 
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?name=%1 [L]
```

Comment: не сработало..

Comment: И не сработает. Ваш браузер должен знать куда запросы отправлять. А для этого он должен запросить IP от адреса petya.test.ru. Но такой информации в ДНС нет, поэтому и не сработает.

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай то есть, по идее, если таки создать субдомен, то работать будет?

Answer (score 2):

В виртуальных хостах прописать имхо

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.host.ru

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/user/www/host/www

    <Directory /home/user/www/host/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: А про ДНС забыли?

Answer (score 0):

Без настроек Apache и записей в NS не обойтись. Но это делается всего один раз.

```
<VirtualHost YOUR_IP:80>
  DocumentRoot "/home/user/www"  
  ServerName "test.ru"
  ServerAlias "test.ru" "*.test.ru"   
  ScriptAlias /cgi/ "/home/user/www/cgi/"
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/oser/www/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>
```

и добавить в NS записях запись типа "А":

```
*    A     YOUR_IP
```

далее в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]+\.)?test\.ru 
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?name=%1 [L]
```

С этого момента все запросы типа: petya|vasya|ya|supermod|test|durak.test.ru

Будут приходить скрипту index.php?name=petya|vasya|ya|supermod|test|durak

А там уж сами знаете что с ними делать.

Comment: мой сайт находится на хостинге, что бы добавить настройки в Апач, нужно общатася в поддержку или есть какой либо файл по фтп? или что вообще,какие действия должны быть что бы добавить настройки в Apache

Comment: @dogmar, на многих хостингах есть опции "создать поддомен", а то и "автоподдомены" (у меня на <a href="http://www.jino.ru">джино</a> есть такое). Мб вам будет проще в техподдержке спросить? Они могут быть у вас вообще запрещены.

Comment: я на агаве,и у меня есть добавить поддомен,но опять же апач остается под вопросом. NS тоже не понятная аббревиатура

Comment: Если есть возможность добавления поддомена, то апач и НС сами настроятся...

Но вам придется для каждого пользователя в ручную создавать поддомены.

И попробуйте добавить поддомен с именем "*" (звездочка).

Comment: вручную это калхоз. у меня юзеры регятся каждый день..

Comment: А я вам о чем?

Ну попросите хостера чтобы он добавил записи в настройках апач и НС.

А если получиться добавить поддомен "*" без кавычек, ничего не надо.

Добавляете поддомен звездочка, и настраиваете .htaccess должно заработат.

Comment: @ЁхарныйБабай этот htaccess в корень сайта кидать или в www?