# Настройка редиректа в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Всей доброго времени суток!

Знаю, что через .htaccess можно настроить редиректы. И если ссылка выглядит так:

```
http://site.ru/page.php?id=mtjvd
```

то её можно сделать так:

```
http://site.ru/page/mtjvd
```

И вот у меня какой вопрос, а как сделать так, чтобы ссылка выглядела так:

```
http://mtjvd.site.ru/
```

Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Посмотрите на РутКоде: [перенаправление с поддомена на папку без переконфигурации Апача](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/142/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, нужно что-то вроде такого

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.site\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://site.ru/page.php?id=$1
```

Comment: тоже не работает(

Comment: Проверьте mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Уже обсуждалось, по-моему, привести ссылку к такому виду - нельзя.

**Дополнено.**

Попробуйте

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^что нужно заменить$  на что
```

например

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin.php 
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.php
```

Надо конкретно директории прописывать. А вообще за такие ссылки банить надо.

Comment: Разве? А как тогда работает сайт homo.com ???

Comment: Я же сказал *по-моему*(!)??? Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: Не работает(

Answer (score 0):

Да не будет это работать!!!!! и никогда не работало...

name.site.ru - это домен третьего уровня
А для всякого домена нужна запись в НС серверах.
вот [тут рабочее решщение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26139/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-htaccess?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#26552), так как я делал и делаю и прекрасно работает

site.ru?page=name - запрос методом GET