# .htaccess Домен третьего уровня из записи в БД

Tags: .htaccess, php, mysql

Простите за столь сумбурное название вопроса. Суть заключается в следующем.

Допустим есть таблица в БД, в таблице есть поле с определенным значением, как это значение передать на домен третьего уровня.

Например: http://mysite.com/value отобразить как http://value.mysite.com/

Страница должна генерироваться исключительно при запросе к БД, без использования файлов и папок где value будет файл(html, php, прочее) или папка на серве.

Дополню для ясности.
В .htaccess есть строка

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-/]+)$ _construct.php [L]
```

В итоге получается ссылка http://mysite.com/value

как методом RewriteRule реализовать чтобы http://value.mysite.com/ было равно http://mysite.com/value и работало одинаково.

Comment: Тоже интересует этот вопрос, создал файл value.php , в .htaccess прописал  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-/]+)$ _construct.php [L]  
И когда я захожу по ссылке http://mysite.com/value то Дэнвер говорит что нет такой страницы

Comment: Моему примеру не совсем стоит следовать, у меня замутов много чтобы работало)

Comment: ну вашему примеру ведь помогли, незная ваших замутов) мне просто понять как работает _construct в .htaccess

Comment: _construct.php состоит из классов которые обрабатывают адрессную строку и выдают информацию по определенному запросу. На простом php будет примерно  выглядеть так:

Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews // тут на усмотрение

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?value=$1 [L]

И в index.php GET запрс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query('select `value` from `locations` where `user_id`=777');
$row = mysql_fetch_object($res);
$new_location = sprintf('Location: http://%s.mysite.com/',$row->value);
header($new_location);
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

Насчет %1 не уверен. Но по-идее, должно быть именно один.

Comment: Спасибо, запрос я построю. Меня интересует конкретно обрабатывающая строка в файле .htaccess которая выдаст вместо http://mysite.com/value -> http://value.mysite.com/

Comment: где %1 возможно будет $1. Пошел пробывать.)

Comment: Нет. доллар был бы, если бы регулярка на той же строчке. Отсыл к кондишну - точно процент

Answer (score 1):

Без записей типа А в настройке домена в ДНС серверах никакого домена третьего уровня вы не получите.... Прочтите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26139/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-htaccess?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#26552)

Comment: Это изнчально все учлось!